# Apache dbd Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, basic-authentication, dbd

I'm trying to use dbd with mysql as authentification with Apache 2.4.

When Apache starts, i have this error :

```
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.789021 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10625:tid 140410697815936] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.789118 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10625:tid 140410697815936] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.789469 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 10628:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to mysql: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.789560 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 10628:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.790282 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 10629:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to mysql: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.790441 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 10629:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.792481 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 10628:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
[Tue May 12 13:07:18.792595 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 10629:tid 140410697815936] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
```

dbd_mysql.conf :

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=192.168.1.2 port=3306 user=MY_USERNAME pass=MY_PASSWORD dbname=MY_DATABASE"
DBDMin  2
DBDKeep 4
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
DBDPersist On
```

000-default.conf

```
[...]
DBDParams "dbname=DATABASENAME"
<IfModule authnz_ldap_module>
    <Directory /var/www/test/>
        AuthName "Authentication"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider dbd
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT SHA2(password, 256) AS password FROM users WHERE username = %s"
        require valid-user
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
[...]
```

If i change the password to put an invalid one, i received the exception

```
Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to mysql: Access denied for user...
```

Debian : 7.8
Apache : 2.4.10
libapr1 : 1.5.1-3 (i tried to downgrade, but i cannot)

Note: The server do not have php nor php+mysql (libphpmysql) installed

Edit :

my.cnf (client part)

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Edit (2) :

I also tried to use the "odbc" for mysql

odbc.ini :

dbd_mysql.conf

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "datasource=MYSERVER_MYSQL_MYDATABASE"
DBDMin  1
DBDKeep 1
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
```

/etc/odbc.ini (i edited the config to remove sensitive data)

```
[MYSERVER_MYSQL_MYDATABASE]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5a.so
Description=MYSERVER_MYSQL_MYDATABASE
SERVER=192.168.1.2
PORT=
USER=MY_USER
Password=MY_PASSWORD
Database=MY_DATABASE
OPTION=3
SOCKET=
```

If i use :

```
# isql MYSERVER_MYSQL_MYDATABASE
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

It working perfectly.. but on the apache error.log :

```
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.323638 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1605:tid 140068309481344] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.323725 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1605:tid 140068309481344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu May 14 09:07:51 2015] [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.323827 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 1608:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to odbc: [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.323870 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 1608:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Thu May 14 09:07:51 2015] [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.324332 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 1609:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to odbc: [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.324430 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 1609:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.331767 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 1608:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
[Thu May 14 09:07:51.331823 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 1609:tid 140068309481344] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
```

Edit (3) :

I found that i did not register the driver :

```
./myodbc-installer -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver" -t "DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5a.so"
```

Then changed the "dbd_mysql.conf" with :

```
DBDriver odbc
DBDParams "CONNECT='DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};SERVER=192.168.1.2;DATABASE=MY_DATABASE;UID=MY_USER;PWD=MY_PASSWORD;'"
DBDMin  1
DBDKeep 1
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
```

But still the same problem (error.log) :

```
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.905733 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5215:tid 140452627486592] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri May 15 09:38:31 2015] [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.905842 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 5218:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to odbc: [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.905888 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 5218:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Fri May 15 09:38:31 2015] [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.906424 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 5219:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00629: Can't connect to odbc: [dbd_odbc] Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1) at /tmp/buildd/apr-util-1.5:1146
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.906528 2015] [dbd:error] [pid 5219:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00633: failed to initialise
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.915211 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 5218:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
[Fri May 15 09:38:31.915578 2015] [dbd:crit] [pid 5219:tid 140452627486592] (20014)Internal error: AH00636: child init failed!
```

Comment: Is mysql running and/or is that the correct location for the socket file? because apache's trying to use the socket file, while your config is trying to tell it to use a TCP connection.

Comment: Mysql server is running on another server. I did not set any socket file..

Comment: well, apache's trying to connect via the socket, so something in your configuration is wrong.

Comment: I posted the content of all the files i have modified. Do you have any idea where the configuration could be wrong ?

Comment: no idea. but apache config can be spread across many many files. maybe there's another authnz module elsewhere that's doing its own connection.

Comment: But i think it's might not be related to the "socket" thing.. because i would not of received the "access denied for user..." when i typed the wrong password.

Comment: What does your my.cnf show? You might have `Skip-networking` enabled. You would need to comment that out.

Comment: There is not reference to "skip-networking" in the my.cnf

Comment: Is there a better place to post this kind of question?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBDParams must be separated with comma: `DBDParams param1=value1[,param2=value2]`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dbd.html

Comment: I changed the ";" to "," `DBDParams "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver},SERVER=192.168.1.2,DATABASE=MY_DATABASE,UID=MY_USER,PWD=MY_PASSWORD"`, still the same error : `Invalid DBD Parameters - open returned SQL_ERROR (-1)`

Comment: My answer will help with your first case with `DBDriver mysql`

In the second case it seems that dbd cant' find ODBC driver by given name.

Comment: Thanks, it works! configuration : `DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=192.168.1.2,user=MY_USER,pass=MY_PASSWORD,dbname=MY_DATABASE"
DBDMin  1
DBDKeep 1
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
DBDPersist On`

Answer (score 0):

in my.conf try

```
[client]
protocol=tcp
```

The reference [Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html) provides an explanation of how to override the default connection methodology.

The reference [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html) vaguely explains what values can be placed in the my.conf file.  Essentially an argument that can be passed to the mysql command on the command line (ie. --protocol) can be specified, without the dashes, in the option file.